# Gitlab CI ignores jobs in child-pipleine

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I built a `.gitlab-ci-yaml` which looks like this and triggers two child-pipelines:

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - triggers

include: 'global-gitlab-ci.yaml'

...

frontend:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: frontend-gitlab-ci.yaml

backend:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: backend-gitlab-ci.yaml
```

the child-pipelines both look like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

include: 'global-gitlab-ci.yaml'

test_frontend:
  stage: test
  image: ...
  script:
    - ...

build_frontend:
  stage: build
  image: ...
  script:
    - ...
```

When I run this pipelines, I get the following:
[image]

The frontend-pipeline (as well as the backend-pipeline) only shows one job - the second one is ignored.

What's the matter? Is the child-pipline not supposed to contain a complete pipeline with several jobs?

(Btw *global-gitlab-ci.yaml* just contains `default:` definitions)

Comment: There's nothing about Child Pipelines or Triggers that would prevent them from working the way you want. Do any of your jobs across any of your pipeline definition files have a `rules` or `only` clause? or `when`?

Comment: @AdamMarshall I am in a similar setup with `when: manual` on the parent job that means the child pipeline is skipped when I manually click on the parent job that has the `include`. Is there anything we should consider with those extra keywords?

Comment: @Datz, Also, what's in the `global-gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: @TPPZ Can you post yours in a new question with all your .yml files? Won't be much help without seeing those.

Comment: @AdamMarshall now I am not sure I see the same issue, anyway still the same type of parent/child pipeline in this question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69373488/gitlab-child-parent-pipeline-in-self-hosted-ci-vm-with-gitlab-runner