# GitLab Child Parent pipeline in self hosted CI VM with gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

I have defined a separate GitLab pipeline on a dedicated YAML file `np-pipeline.yml`. Then I call it from another manual job with the `trigger` feature:

```
job:manual:new-np:
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab-ci/np-pipeline.yml
  when: manual
```

I basically followed the docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#child--parent-pipelines

However I am not able to run the whole child pipeline. The issue is with the amber icon below in the image with the flow. **The first job in the child pipeline flow is stuck** with this message:

> This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it. Go to project CI settings

Overview of the parent/child flow:

[image: parent/child flow]

I have a self-hosted `gitlab-runner` configured in a Virtual Machine I own that is registered with various GitLab projects (repositories) and groups that I administer.

When I go to the repository (project) CI settings I don't see any new token I could use to register another GitLab runner.

I've already registered a project runner with a command similar to:

```sh
gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
    --registration-token "MY_TOKEN" \
    --description "devops runner, using MY_TOKEN token" \
    --tag-list "my_devops, MY_TOKEN" \
    --executor "shell"
```

**I have also registered some group runners with separate tokens**, but when I

1. go on the GitLab website project page
2. then click on the "Settings" on the left panel
3. then click on "CI/CD"
4. then expand the "Runners" section:

they don't appear in the project list of available tokens. I can only see the one project runner I registered with the command above.

- **How do I run this CI parent/child pipeline in a self-hosted CI VM with GitLab runners?**
- I would like to use `shell` runners (no docker or anything else)
- I have quite a big VM for the CI jobs so I am trying to see if there's a way to have multiple runners in the same VM.

The separate child pipeline for reference:

```yaml
job-np-queues:
  script: 
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 40m

job-np-endpoint-api:
  needs: [job-np-queues]
  script: 
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 20m

job-np-partner-api:
  needs: [job-np-queues]
  script: 
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 20m

job-np-apisnapshot-blob:
  needs: [job-np-queues]
  script: 
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 15m

job-integration-tests-apis:
  needs: [job-np-endpoint-api, job-np-partner-api, job-np-apisnapshot-blob]
  script: 
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 30m
  retry:
    max: 1


job-acceptance-tests-apis:
  needs: [job-integration-tests-apis]
  script:
    - echo "DO THINGS"
  timeout: 20m
  retry:
    max: 1
```

Comment: Do you have Shared Runners configured for your project? They should show up as available runners in the Runners CI/CD Settings section, along with your project Runner. There will be a button under the "Shared Runners" header that will say "Disable shared runners" if it's already enabled, otherwise "Enable shared runners".

Comment: Shared runners are not enabled, because they're from GitLab whereas I would like to use my own runners (project or group runners). There are enabled Group Runners for this project, there's a green dot beside them, however they don't seem to be picked up. Both Project and Group runners are actually the same `gitlab-runner` instance in the VM with the same TOML conf.

Comment: If you go to the runner's list for the Group, hit the pencil button to edit it, there's a checkbox that could be affecting your desired outcome. The first is labeled `Run untagged jobs`. It will depend on your unique situation to know if this should be checked or not for your runners, but if it is selected but you aren't using tags, then uncheck it. Runners for the entire instance have another checkbox that locks it to projects it's currently assigned to, but it doesn't appear to be the case for Group runners (probably Project runners too). Are your projects enabled for the runner?